# SSLSocket in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have code:

```
public void Connection()
{
    TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 5030);
    server.Start();

    while (true)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Waiting for client");
        TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
        ProcessClient(TcpClient client);              
    }
}
```

Can someone explain me why I cannot use AcceptTcpClient? Only this Async version? And how should I use this function? I am using this example 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.net.security.sslstream(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I believe you need to use await  keyword

Comment: You can use `AcceptTcpClient`.  What makes you think otherwise?

Comment: This code wont compile. Please post [mcve]

Comment: @Amy: .Net Core (in general) only has async APIs

Comment: @SLaks ah okay, i didn't notice the question was .Net Core.

Comment: @Amy the compiler? He throws me exception when I try :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.net Core is all based on the asynchronous philosophy to achieve the maximum performance, hence a lot of synchronous methods have been removed because they're unnecessary.

To use the new async code you must use the `await` keyword to "stop" your code until the asynchornous function has been executed, and flag your function as `async` to be able to use the `await` keyword.

```
public async Task Connection()
{
    TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 5030);
    server.Start();

    while (true)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Waiting for client");
        TcpClient client = await server.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
        ProcessClient(TcpClient client);              
    }
}
```

BUT, beware, by what you're asking you never have used async, so don't jump to code until you read what is and how works async on .net or you will live a nightmare as a lot of things will not work as you expect. And as I said, if you target .net Core, async is not optional.

Comment: thanks for answer but I tried this code before(I mean use await) and I have information that "The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'."

Comment: @Nju: Did you actually read the error? You need to do exactly what it's telling you to do.  Learn about `async` methods.

Comment: Please, read THE FULL CODE, as you will see the function has been marked as `async task` and that's what will allow you to use `await`. I've even explained it on the text...